# dependsOnGroup not working with beforeclass

Tags: testng

Does dependsonGroup work with beforeClass?

My code is like:

```
@BeforeClass(dependsOnGroups = { "init" })
public void setup() throws Exception
{
//some code
}

@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "init" })
public void test() throws Exception
{
//some code
}
```

init group has some test methods from a different class.

In my case, if init fails the Test methods marked with dependsOnGroups = { "init" } are skipped but not beforeClass methods.

Is there any other way to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that beforeclass(or afterclass) doesn't accept dependsonGroup parameter...we can use beforemethod (if applicable in the case).

I solved my problem by setting a flag in init methods to false if they fail and using it in beforeclass as:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setup() throws Exception
{
 if(flag==true)
 {
 //some code
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour.

I think what you can do is

```
@beforeClass(dependsOnGroups= {"init"})
public setUp(){
}
```

for the beforeClass as well. Which should solve your problem

Another thing you can do is have afterClass and do runAlways=true. And in that aftetClass you can undo whatever you have done in the beforeClass even if the actual test skips. (Here I am assuming that your problem is you are doing something in beforeClass and they are not used in the actual test method)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be expected behavior..

@BeforeClass annotation:-
**Note**- methods tagged with @Before/After will not be part of the final report. 
 **setup()** is not a '@Test' and hence, its not skipped even though dependent group method **init** fails.

@Test annotation:-
If a method depended upon(method which is part of a group, here **'init'**) fails, and you have a hard dependency on it (alwaysRun=false, which is by default), the methods that depend on it(here **test()**) are **not** marked as FAIL but as SKIP. Skipped @Test methods will be reported as such in the testNG report; because it is important since skipped methods may not be failures.

if you want @Test method to run even though dependent group method fails, then use a soft dependency. It is obtained by adding "alwaysRun=true" in your @Test annotation.

syntax:-
@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "init" }, alwaysRun=true)

- Here **test()** will always run after the groups you depend on, even if some of them have failed.